# jquery data table is not applied to the table

Tags: jquery, spring, jsp

i don't know why jquery data table is not applied to my table. i have exactly the same code in another jsp page and it is working perfectly well. but when i want to apply it to this jsp it doesn't work, although the code is the same. here is the jsp page:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<!DOCTYPE html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr">

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>title</title>
    <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
<%@include file="headerFragment.jsp" %>

<div class="container-fluid main">

    <div class="row" style="padding: 20px;">
            <div>
                <table id="tblManage" class="table table-hover" style="table-layout: fixed;">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th width="15%">عنوان</th>
                        <th width="23%">توضیحات</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="manage-rows" style="word-wrap:break-word;">
                    <c:forEach items="${polls}" var="deb">
                        <tr>
                            <td>${deb.title}</td>
                            <td style="word-wrap: break-word">${deb.description}</td>
                            <td><a class="dontSelect" href="/user/viewPoll/${deb.poll_id}" style="text-decoration: none">مشاهده</a></td>
                            <td><a class="dontSelect" href="/admin/edit-poll/${deb.poll_id}" style="text-decoration: none">ویرایش</a></td>
                            <td><c:choose>
                                <c:when test="${deb.expired.equals('N')}">
                                <a href="/admin/expire-poll/${deb.poll_id}" style="text-decoration: none">منقضی کردن</a>
                            </c:when>
                                <c:otherwise>
                                    <a href="/admin/unexpire-poll/${deb.poll_id}" style="text-decoration: none">تمدید</a>
                                </c:otherwise>
                            </c:choose>
                               </td>
                            <td>
                                <c:choose>
                                    <c:when test="${deb.enabled.equals('Y')}">
                                        <a href="/admin/disable-poll/${deb.poll_id}" style="text-decoration: none">غیر فعال کردن</a>
                                    </c:when>
                                    <c:otherwise>
                                        <a href="/admin/enable-poll/${deb.poll_id}" style="text-decoration: none">فعال کردن</a>
                                    </c:otherwise>
                                </c:choose></td>
                            <td><a href="/admin/delete-poll/${deb.poll_id}" style="text-decoration: none">حذف</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
<%@include file="footerFragment.jsp" %>


<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/datatables.js"></script>
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<%--<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/create-poll.js"></script>--%>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tblManage").dataTable({
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "bAutoWidth": false,
            searching: true, paging: true, info: false, LengthChange: true
        });
        $('table').removeClass('dataTable');
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

does it have anything to do with where i put the script?

please note that the same style sheets and scripts are working in another jsp page. is this because i am using the same data table twice??

Answer (score 2):

Try remove this:

```
$('table').removeClass('dataTable');
```

Comment: I did it and it didn't work. I put it to remove the 'datatable' class it adds to the table. It has nothing to do with javascript or sth. I think maybe it is due to where to put the script tag. Because even with not removing this line, it still does't omit "datatable' class. Any idea?